# Question about pro-representable Automorphism functor in Sernesi's "Deformations of algebraic schemes" with trivial relative Tangent space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of arbitrary characteristic, $R$ a complete local noetherian, *but non Artinian* (see *#Edit* below for justification) $k$-algebra with residue field $k$ and $S$ a complete local $R$-algebra also with residue field $k$. Assume, that

$$ \operatorname{Hom}_{R\text{-alg}}(S, k[\epsilon]) = 0 $$

(ie the zero space as we can regard it as $k$-vs) where the ring of dual numbers $ k[\epsilon]=k[x]/(x^2)$ is endowed with the structure of $R$-algebra via the canonical map $R \to k \to  k[\epsilon] $.

**Question:** Why does this imply $S=R$? E.g., why cannot $R \to S$ be a proper surjection with nontrivial kernel?

Background: This is claimed in Edoardo Sernesi's "[Deformations of Algebraic Schemes](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-30615-3)" in the first line of the proof of Corollary 2.6.4, page 92. The used notations as for $S$ is adapted from Proposition 2.6.2.
More concretely the precise context there is that the proposition states $S$ pro-represents a certain functor

$$ \operatorname{Aut}_{\hat{u}}: (\text{local Artinian } R\text{-algebras with residue field } k) \to (\text{sets}) $$

and by assumption & pro-representability $\operatorname{Hom}_{R\text{-alg}}(S, k[\epsilon]) =\operatorname{Aut}_{\hat{u}}( k[\epsilon])=0$ Geometrically - on level of associated schemes - this tells that $S$ has relative dimension $0$ over $R$. From this the author deduces $R=S$, that's not clear to me. There are no assumptions that the rings are domains.

Remark: In the context of Prop 2.6.2 $(R,\hat{u})$ is called semi-universal couple, see Definition 2.2.3. page 47, but as we already know that the functor above is pro-representable by $S$, it suffice to forget the stuff about Aut functor above and to focus only on the natural functor $\operatorname{Hom}_R(S, -)$ induced by $S$ only.
A bit loosely related with [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/364551/question-about-automorphism-functor-in-sernesis-deformations-of-algebraic-sche) (at least same book, proposition and used notations), but different problem.

**#EDIT:** As LSpice pointed out there are counterexamples if $R, S$ Artinian (indeed, every Artinian is complete), so we should assume that $R,S$ complete, but **not Artinian**.

Comment: I'm confused how the situation that you describe can ever arise—isn't the map $R \to k \to k[\epsilon]$ an $R$-algebra homomorphism $R \to k[\epsilon]$, so that $\operatorname{Hom}_{\text{$R$-alg}}(S, k[\epsilon])$ is non-$0$ even if $S$ does equal $R$?

Comment: @LSpice: But if $R=S$, then as you said $R \to k \to k[\epsilon]$ is the unique(!) member of $\operatorname{Hom}_{\text{$R$-alg}}(R, k[\epsilon])$ corresponding to the "zero" if we identify $\operatorname{Hom}_{\text{$R$-alg}}(R, k[\epsilon])$ with $k$-vs $H^1(X,T_X)$, cp with  [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/364551/question-about-automorphism-functor-in-sernesis-deformations-of-algebraic-sche). Note that the "real" zero map $R \to 0 \to k[\epsilon]$ not lives in $\operatorname{Hom}_{\text{$R$-alg}}(R, k[\epsilon])$ since not respects the $R$-alg structure.

Comment: Or did I misunderstood your concern? Please correct me if that's the case.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464759/question-about-pro-representable-automorphism-functor-in-sernesis-deformations#comment1207196_464759), no, sorry, you understood perfectly; I just was being careless (although I do think that, even for someone reading more carefully than I, it may be confusing to use $0$ for the set containing only the structure homomorphism, without explicitly mentioning the identification in the [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464759/question-about-pro-representable-automorphism-functor-in-sernesis-deformations#comment1207195_464759)!).

Comment: @LSpice: thanks, I should point this out.

Comment: So, now that I understand your question correctly, haven't you given a counterexample—if, for example, $R = k[\epsilon]$ and $S = k$, with the obvious $R$-algebra structure on $S$, then $\operatorname{Hom}_{\text{$R$-alg}}(S, k[\epsilon])$ contains only the inclusion?

Comment: @LSpice: That should work. Do you see maybe a counterexample, if we assume $R$ and $S$ to be complete, but *non Artinian* :) The background was that the pair $(R,u)$ is semi-universal wrt deformation functor $Def_X$ that means that $h_R \to Def_X$ is smooth. For terminology, see Thm 2.6.1 in the book. Maybe this excludes $R, S$ to be Artin... thanks for this point!

Comment: @LSpice: this also heuristically/geometrically makes no sense in the context of the book as " realive smoothness" intuitively looks locally like affine space (="domain") over the base (="target"), so it makes already heuristically no sense that $R$ has dimension zero (as any Artin ring), but $Def_X$ positive one... so I expect that the $R, S$ should be assumed to be non Artin...

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464759/question-about-pro-representable-automorphism-functor-in-sernesis-deformations#comment1207217_464759), I don't, unfortunately, but this is well outside my expertise, so that doesn't say anything about whether or not it's true.